# How to call a JavaScript function from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a school project and I need some help. I'm suposed to make a drop down menu which allows the user to change font-size, font-type and backgroundcolor of the text they are reading. My problem is that I can't get my functions to run. I'm new to this, so I don't know if the problem is how I try to call for it or if the function i flawed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdownmeny.css">
 <h1>Javascript</h1>

</head>

<body>
<p></p>
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Font-size</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="liten()">15px</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="medium()">20px</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="stor()">25px</a>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    <li><a href="#">Font-type</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Verdana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Times New Roman</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Arial</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Bakgrunnsfarge</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Rosa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Turkis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gul</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<p id=tekst style="background-color:pink; font-size: 15px; font-family: verdana">This text should change</p>
<script>function liten() {document.getElementById("tekst").style.font-size = "15px"; }</script>
<script>function medium() {document.getElementById("tekst").style.font-size = "20px"; }</script>
<script>function stor() {document.getElementById("tekst").style.font-size = "25px"; }</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I only have the functions for the font-size here, but i guess it will be the same for all of them. English isn't my first language, but I hope I have been clear enough. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to add a handler (which calls your function) to the changing of the drop down

Comment: `<p id=tekst` should be `<p id="tekst"`

Comment: You should use style.fontSize or style[font-size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good but you have some syntax errors.

- You must write `id="tekst"` instead of `id=tekst`
- `font-size` is not a valid identifier in javascript (because of the `-`), so you must use the array notation to access it.

Here is a working example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <h1>Javascript</h1>

</head>

<body>
<p></p>
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Font-size</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="liten()">15px</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="medium()">20px</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="stor()">25px</a>
            </ul>
        </li>   
    <li><a href="#">Font-type</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Verdana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Times New Roman</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Arial</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Bakgrunnsfarge</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Rosa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Turkis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gul</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<p id="tekst" style="background-color:pink; font-size: 15px; font-family: verdana">This text should change</p>
<script>function liten() {document.getElementById("tekst").style['font-size'] = "15px"; }</script>
<script>function medium() {document.getElementById("tekst").style['font-size'] = "20px"; }</script>
<script>function stor() {document.getElementById("tekst").style['font-size'] = "25px"; }</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to call change event on drop downs.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, you answer in jQuery while his code is plain javascript.  -1.